# Meteor: Get level information of a looping template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using a 'loop'-template to display elements and it's subelements. So if the structure is three level deep, the loopIt-template is used three times.

```
<template name="main">
    {{ < loopIt }}
</template>

<template name="loopIt">
    {{#each elements}}
        {{title}} {{level}}
        {{ > loopIt }}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Is it possible to get the information in which level the element is and output this as `{{level}}`?

The result should look like this:

```
first element 1
    first subelement 2
    second subelement 2
        first subsubelement 3
    third subelement 2
second element 1
```

Comment: don't you have on your data model the level? Would be easier to handle that from your data than with Blaze or "custom dirty tricks"

Comment: I'm using a model tree structure with parent references. So I don't have the level info. Just only reference to next parent of each element :-(

Comment: Do you generate the tree? If yes I would just add the level info on each node when you build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

First, define a helper to increment the level as you go deeper in the recursion

```
Template.loopIt.helpers({
  add: function(level) {
    return level + 1;
  }
});
```

Then in the template pass the current level and increment it with the defined helper as you go in the next level of the recursion.

```
<template name="main">
    {{ < loopIt level = 0}}
</template>

<template name="loopIt">
    {{#each elements}}
        {{title}} {{../level}} 
        {{ > loopIt level = (add ../level)}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Note that in the `each` loop you lose the parent context. In order to access the parent context again, it is necessary to prefix the variable `level` with `../`